# In what cases should i use self keyword?

Tags: python

I have a simple question but which confuses me for a long time.
This is the example code:

```
class test():
    def func(self):
        
        lst = []
        self.num = 0
        
        def method(tmp):
            lst.append(tmp)
            self.num += 1
        
        method(1)
```

The question is, why do I need to add `self` before `num`, but for `lst`, i dont need to do that?

`self.num` is making `num` global inside `func`?

Comment: Because both `self` and `lst` are mutable but `num` on its own is not. `self.num += 1` is mutating the instance. `num += 1` is assigning a new `int` object to `num`.

Comment: Thanks. i got it now.

Comment: Note that `self` is not a keyword: it is just the name conventionally given to the first parameter that references to the instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the self the code doesn't work because [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47264416/10875953), But this code will:

```
class test():
    def func(self):
        
        lst = []
        num = 0
        
        def method(tmp):
            nonlocal num
            lst.append(tmp)
            num += 1
        
        method(1)
```

This is because a list is mutable, and so it will not make a copy when editing the value of lst. While when the value of num is changed, it will make a new variable (local num). see docs [nonlocal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?#nonlocal)

Note you cannot access num outside of `func`. So this will not work(while it previously would)

```
t = test()
t.func()
print(t.num) # doesn't exist!
```

Answer (score 2):

`self` is a reference to the instance of the class. So, `self.num` is referencing the property `num` on the instance, while `lst` is a local variable to that method.

```py
class test:
    def func(self):
        self.lst = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        lst = [5, 6, 7, 8]
        print(self.lst) # [0, 1, 2, 3]
        print(lst) # [5, 6, 7, 8]

    def test(self):
        print(self.lst) # [0, 1, 2, 3]
        print(lst) # Error

i = test()
i.func()
i.test() # Error, see above
```

Comment: I don't think you get my question. I am asking why ```lst``` does not need ```self```, but ```num``` needs it..

Comment: Because `lst` is a local variable to the function, while `num` is a property of the instance

Comment: That's why if you call `i = test(); i.func(); i.test()`, it throws an error because `lst` doesn't exist. `lst` is local to `func`

Comment: @2pichar if you look at OP's question, the `method` function is an inner function and not an actual method. Your example just has 2 methods.

Answer (score 1):

`func` is member function of the class.  `method` is just a standalone function, unrelated to the class.  In order to call `func`, you have to say:

```
obj.func()
```

Python handles that by automatically passing the `obj` as the first parameter, which we have traditionally called `self`.  But to call `method`, you just say:

```
method(1)
```

There is no object, so there is no automatic creating of a first parameter.  When you refer to `self` and `num` inside of `method`, you're referring to the local variables in the outer function, which it inherits.